# Get more recent statuses for a list of userids with twitter4j

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

Im using twitter4j in java

I got a *Set idsSet* with some twitter usersIds.
I'm trying to get the 20 most recent status with 'getUserTimeline' for each userID.

```
for(Long id : idsSet)
{
   statusMap.put(id,twitter.getUserTimeline(id));
}
```

The problem is that I only get the statuses for 180 users every 15 mins.

My question is

is there a way to get more users every 15 mins? like with the 'lookupUsers' thats holds up to 100 usersIds per request allowing 18k every 15 mins

Comment: There is no way of bypassing the Rate Limits. No.

Comment: Not bypassing the rate limits. Just want to know if that is the max users I can get. It doesn't feel right that I can only get statuses for 180 users compare with the 18k lookupUsers give.

Answer (score 0):

The twitter API description for [users](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/users/lookup) specifies that you can get the information of 100 users for request. In the same way, you can use the attribute **count** to control how many tweets you get with one request (up to 200), this is specified [here](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline). Now, as twitter4j is a wrapper around these GET requests, you need to configure you call with a [Paging](https://github.com/yusuke/twitter4j/blob/master/twitter4j-core/src/main/java/twitter4j/Paging.java) object. It would be something like this:

```
Paging page = new Paging (1, 200);
twitter.getUserTimeline(id,page);
```

Comment: This works to get more tweets, I'm looking to get more users. Thanks anyway